# How does it work when I run two ninja commands (the 2nd begins before the 1st completes) in the same directory. Will it cause undefined behaviors?

Tags: cmake, ninja

I'm wondering how it works when I run two ninja commands (the 2nd begins before the 1st completes) in the same directory.

The 1st one is still linking, but the 2nd one is re-building a target (that's possibly being used) in the 1st command anytime.

I didn't see a violent warning message or error, so wondering if it would cause undefined behavior, or introduces bugs silently.

Comment: `Will it cause undefined behaviors?` You would have to define that term _for that context_.

Comment: By `undefined behaviors`, I'm thinking of this case
1) A build is going (not completed) and generating many object files.
2) A link starts, so read updated object file 1 (generated in 1)), and read stale object file 2

This may not generate bugs, but still usually a scenario that I want to avoid since it's hard to reason about the combination of object files.

Answer (score 1):

> How does it work when I run two ninja commands (the 2nd begins before the 1st completes) in the same directory.

Two processes run at the same time - that's normal operation for multiprocess operating systems that we use. Nothing out of the ordinary.

Maybe you are asking... - no, there is no blocking mechanism implemented in ninja to protect against concurrent execution.

> Will it cause undefined behaviors?

You would have to define the meaning of that term. The term "undefined behavior" is commonly used in the context of the family of C programming language, where it means it that the behavior is undefined **in some standard**.

The behavior here will be a result of a race condition - two processes access, write and read, to the same set of files concurrently. That's nothing out of the ordinary. Whoever wins and executes first, is first, the other is second - there is ordering, the behavior is "defined" in the context that kernel will protect against data corruption at file system level and either one or the other process will win the race, for example to write to a specific file,

> or introduces bugs silently.

That strongly depends on the specific case - what actually happens, how your build system was configured, what the dependency is. If the first ninja compiles for x86 architecture, but the second one cross-compiles for `arm-none-eabi` architecture, the resulting set of files will be incompatible. The incompatibility can be more subtle, ergo can introduce bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  This answers my original question. I'll need to run `ninja` in two separate build directories then to avoid any race conditions when I do need to avoid races.